# How to move * to the right or left, based on input? [C++]

Tags: c++

So, I want to write a c++ program, so it can move *, based on user imput, the user will be able to move it left or right as many times they want.

```
cout << "*" << endl;
cout << Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right): << endl;
cin >> c;

while (c == 'k' || c == 'l'){
  if(c == 'k'){
```

That's what I have so far and I don't know how to proceed. 
Thanks in advance for any suggestions/help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char c='x';
    int position = 0; //starts from the left most position
    int temp =0;
    cout << "*" << endl;
    cout << "Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): " << endl;
    cin >> c;

while (c != 'x')
{
    if((c == 'r')||(c=='l'))
    {
        if(c == 'r')
        {
        position++;
        }
        else if(c == 'l')
        {
        if(position==0) 
            position=0;
        else
            position--;
        }
        temp=position;
        while(temp--!=0)
        {
        cout << " "; //print space
        }
        cout << "*" <<endl;
    }   
    else
    {
        cout << "Wrong character entered\n" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): "<< endl;
    cin >> c;
}
return 0;
```

}

Input:

```
rrrrrrrlllx
```

Output:

```
*
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): 
 *
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): 
  *
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): 
   *
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): 
    *
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): 
     *
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): 
      *
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): 
       *
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): 
      *
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): 
     *
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit): 
    *
Enter: l (Move Left) or r (Move Right) or x (exit):
```

Comment: How do you move more than 2 or more things?

Comment: Well, your question and the kind of input you had provided, didn't ask for it. For what you asked, you need to enter `l` or `r` as many times as you want it to move left or right

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, to clarify. How do you move two or more things if I wanted to use this program again Eg To make a shape [Triangle or Square], how can you move the whole thing?

Comment: For that, you can take two inputs from the user: 1) `l` or `r` 2) how many positions you want to move. In this 2nd case, add/subtract the no. of positions from the `position` variable in the above code accordingly.

Comment: I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Ummm kind of, but here's the code i'm working with. Hopefully the link works   [link](http://shrib.com/a5w629ll)

Comment: Also , is it possible to assign a shape, eg as shown above, to something? I.e An array of ints, or chars?